# C# webrequest to curl

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to make a GET request to following url

```
[ ~ ] $ curl -u duff:X https://subs.pinpayments.com/api/v4/sitename/subscribers/7388.xml
```

where `-u` is username and then `X` is password.

How to use `WebRequest`?

Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

The [WebRequest class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has a **Credentials** property, which you can set:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Another possibility would be to use the [WebClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.WebClient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), that supports [custom credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.credentials%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) too:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
//Byte[] pageData = client.DownloadData(url);
//string pageHtml = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(pageHtml);
// or DownloadString: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
var pageHtml = client.DownloadString(uri);
Console.WriteLine(pageHtml);
```

If you need for a reason to set custom [header information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.headers%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the request, then the *WebClient* class could be more suitable.